# Querying method and approach to check if user is subscribed to specified news and return them

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am currently working with Entity Framework Core and Net Core 2.1 web app learning about how to indicate if a user is subscribed to specified news or not.

I spent a day trying to understand how to work with the Linq query method for this case:

1. I have 3 tables (Users, News and Subscriptions)

   1.1. In the `Subscriptions` table the news id must be stored, which is the one that the user subscribed (next to the user id)
2. It is assumed that when a user subscribes they can receive notifications from the news, otherwise not.

My problem comes when I try to check if the user is subscribed to that specified news. I also need to return the news that person is subscribed to (I am basically failing to query properly). I tried with the `Include()` method but I feel like I am missing something.

This is my code:

DataContext:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>
{
    public DbSet<News> News { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<Subscription>(s => 
        {
             s.HasKey(x => new
             {
                 x.UserId,
                 x.NewsId
             });
        });
    }
}
```

User entity:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

`News` entity:

```
public class News
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Content { get; set; }

     public ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}
```

Subscription entity:

```
public class Subscription
{
     public string UserId { get; set; }
     public string NewsId { get; set; }
     public News News { get; set; }
     public User User { get; set; }
}
```

`NewsModel` model used in View (UserModel contains the same essential properties as User):

```
public class NewsModel
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
     public string Content { get; set; }

     public UserModel UserCreate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` and `News` have a many-to-many relationship in which `Subscription` is the connection between both classes.

The general pattern for querying many-to-many associations is

```cs
from news in context.News
from un in news.Subscriptions
let user = un.User
select ...
```

And now you can `select` any property from `news` and `user` to present data from both classes in a flat list.

```cs
select new NewsModel
{
    Id = news.Id,
    Title = news.Title,
    Content = news.Content,
    UserCreate = new UserModel
    {
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName
    }
}
```

Side note: I would use a name like `NewsItem`, easier to distinct singular and plural names.

Comment: Now it works nicely, thanks. Now I have to ask if there is a way to make it work with Linq Methods. Also thanks for the side note, i'll keep it in mind always

Comment: `from` - `from` is the query-syntax equivalent of `SelectMany`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60006795/861716). You'll see why I always use query syntax for this type of query.

Comment: That's a good example, thanks!. I will try it very soon but at the moment I am satisfied with the answer.